# ENUM retornando apenas a chave e não o valor

Tags: java, java-ee, enums

estou tentando de varias formas obter o valor de um ENUM, mas o mesmo apenas me retorna seu "chave". Abaixo segue o ENUM:

```
public enum SaleType {
    BOUGHT("Comprou"),
    SEND_BUDGET("Enviar Orçamento"),
    SUBMITTED_BUDGET("Orçamento Enviado"),
    NOT_WANTED("Não quis"),
    MAYBE_FUTURE("Pode Querer no Futuro");

    private final String sale ;

    private SaleType(String sale){
        this.sale=sale;
    }

    public String getSaleType(){
        return sale;
    }

}
```

Por exemplo, quero obter o "conteúdo" do **SEND_BUDGET**, logo fiz um laço no qual irá pegar todos os valores do meu ENUM e fazer um IF para comparar se o valor bate...

```
 for (SaleType s : SaleType.values()) {
    if (si.getSaleType().equals(s)) {
        String name = si.getSaleType();
        SaleType valueOf = s.valueOf(SaleType.class, name);
        System.out.println(valueOf);
    }
}
```

Mas o problema é que sempre ele vai me retornan a chave Ex:. **SEND_BUDGET** e não o seu valor correspondente "Enviar Orçamento".

Provavelmente é uma duvida basica, mas já tentei algumas formas e sem suceso

Comment: Por um acaso `si` é do tipo `SaleType`? Se for, enums são um dos poucos casos em que é seguro se comparar com `==` (i.e. troque seu `if` para `si == s`).

Comment: Sim @mgibsonbr o meu si é do tipo SaleType. Interessante! Irei por em pratica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use da seguinte maneira:

```
SaleType.SEND_BUDGET.getSaleType()
```

Comment: Exato! Falta de atenção a minha.